# Mongoose query using req.body not returning correct data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to retrieve data from the database using the Mongoose `Model.find()` function, passing along whatever parameters I get from `req.body` as well as the parameter `req.user._id` as my query.

So far what I've done is put the `req.user._id` inside my `req.body` and then passing them to `Post.find()` as follows:

```
getUserPosts: function(req, res) {
        req.body.user = "" + req.params.id;
        var query = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        Post.find(query, function(err, posts) {
            if(err) return res.status(500).json({error: unknownError});
            else if(posts) return res.status(200).json({posts});
        });
    }
```

The problem is; I keep getting data results that do not match the query I am sending. What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly... remove that `JSON.stringify` part. The query parameter requires key/value object comprising of field names (key) that should match with values specified. For example var query = { _id: req.body._id }.

Second... What is that `req.body.user = req.params.id`?

Final code:

```
getUserPosts: function(req, res) {
    var query = { _id: req.params.id };
    Post.find(query, function(err, posts) {

        if(err) return res.status(500).json({error: unknownError});
        else if(posts) return res.status(200).json({posts});
    });
}
```

Comment: I am adding a field `user` in `req.body` which is equal to the field `req.params.id` so I can send the query like: `{ status: 2,
  user: '586a24d9319242157dcd796e' }` where the value in user is the `req.params.id`.

Comment: The problem really was with `JSON.stringify`. I thought I tried it without it before and it didn't work as well, but obviously not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: why pass the same value in two fields of req.body & params? Also why overwrite it in the function? Sorry but I am unable to understand. So, please tell me the following: **(A)** Where does the value 2 for staus come from? Is it fixed or received in request body. **(B)** The ObjectId value in req.body.user or req.params.id??

Comment: Okay... great... glad it helped you.

Comment: I am not adding `user` in req.body to pass it along. I wanted to have a single query that I can pass to `Post.find(query)` because as far as I know, `Post.find({user: req.params.id, req.body})` is not valid syntax. The reason is, I am searching for posts that belong to a certain user whose id is `req.params.id`, but I may or may not want to filter some posts only using other post parameters like status or date or whatever that may be sent in the `req.body`. The ObjectId is sent in the `req.params.id`. I hope this clarifies your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You defined that `req.body.user = "" + req.params.id;`
I don't know whether the params.id is the Post.user in the post.
Whatever, your req.body became  {user: *id*}

I suggest you print out the object of req.body and see whether it exists in your Post model in mongodb.

Besides, in mongodb, the generated `_id` is an ObjectId instead of string. You are supposed to login to mongodb and understand the format of the data.

See the following example in mongo:

```
> db.Post.find({"_id":"5786d286ed4b71f473efbd99"}) 
// nothing
> db.Post.find({"_id":ObjectId("5786d286ed4b71f473efbd99")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5786d286ed4b71f473efbd99"), "created" : ISODate("2016-07-13T23:45:10.522Z") }
```

Comment: But I am not querying directly using MongoDB. I am using Mongoose and `id` works just fine as a string in Mongoose.